# Command box is not showing full results

Tags: 16.04, update-manager

After pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> on the keyboard to open the run command box and type a command such as `update-manager- cd` the exact result won't show up.

[image: Reference image here]

Comment: Question must first be clarified. Reactions from OP suggest that the issue is not about the Alt+F2 dialog, but about the command `update-manager-cd` not working (should indeed read `update-manager -cd`

Comment: Agreed. Even in the posted image, it appears that the command issued is `update-manager- cd` which also won't work. I've pointed this out in my answer. Even the link quoted by the OP correctly has `update-manager -cd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command is wrong. There's a space missing. You need

```
update-manager -cd
```

Note the space between *update-manager* and *-cd*.

---

I tested <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> in a fully updated VM of Ubuntu 16.04.

Initially, I see this which is logical and self-explanatory:

[image: Image 1]

Then, typing just <kbd>u</kbd>, lists a lot of commands starting with <kbd>u</kbd>:

[image: Image 2]

Typing more stuff in reduces the clutter to just one item:

[image: Image 3]

At this point, if I pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the item would be highlighted and if I then pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, *update manager* would launch.

However, I further need to add the `-c` and `-d` options which can be added by combining them as `-cd`:

[image: Image 4]

Now, I can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or just double-click on the icon showing me `update-manager -cd`.

---

Based on the image you've included, you're not seeing what I've shown above and I can't understand why.

For this reason, I suggest you

- backup your data (images, documents, etc) to an external device
- download the Ubuntu 18.04 iso, make a Live USB, test it as described [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and then
- do a clean install

All the best!

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> run command box works with Tab-completion, much like the bash shell in the terminal. Like in the shell, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> will continue completing the command if there is only one possibility. If there are multiple possibilities, <kbd>Tab</kbd> will not react, just like in the bash shell. However, and here comes the difference, in the bash shell, you can press a second time on <kbd>tab</kbd> to show all possibilities. In the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> run command box, that function is not there: the dialog does not react. Just continue typing one or more letters: at some point, hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> will continue completion.

Comment: `Tab` didn't help me

Comment: Edit your post and indicate exactly what you type, what you expect to see and what does not work according to your expectations. Then we will know better what you actually do, what you actually expect, and be able to better pinpoint what is not according to your expectations.

Comment: I typed `update-manager-cd` as given in a website to upgrade the OS from 16 to 18

Comment: What do you mean with "exact results"? Bear in mind we are not in front of your computer, and we cannot read your mind.

Comment: in this link (https://medium.com/@chiragpatel_52497/upgrading-ubuntu-16-04-lts-to-ubuntu-18-04-lts-15c1288d5f50) they have given an output for the above mentioned `update-manager-cd`.

Comment: Clarify your question by editing. It is utterly unclear. You give the impression that you are looking for autocomplete, but it rather is an issue with the command. As such, you issue is not at all related to the Alt+F2 dialog, but to the command itself. Clarify exactly what you want to know. Make sure to also edit the question title.